# Como pegar os ultimos lançamentos de um inner join

Tags: mysql, join, inner, inner-join

Pessoal to fazendo uma consulta em 3 tabelas com inner join, segue o código:

```
 select 
        itensVenda.idVenda, itensVenda.idProd, itensVenda.qtd,
        produtos.id, produtos.descricao, produtos.foto,
        venda.id, venda.valor
   from produtos 
  INNER JOIN itensVenda ON produtos.id = itensVenda.idProd 
  INNER JOIN venda ON itensVenda.idVenda = venda.id
```

Até ai tudo bem esta pegando tudo, o que eu gostaria:
eu tenho no itensVenda dois id venda iguais no ultimo lançamento, como posso resgatar este lançamento me mostrando o ultimo idVenda?
exemplo: tenho dois id venda 0009 e queria uni-los

Comment: Tenta ...ORDER BY idVenda DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: acredito que você precise agrupar, pode colocar na pergunta um exemplo dos dados que retorna?

Comment: tentei isso mas volta só um resultado sendo que tenho dois id venda

Comment: ele retorna assim:

Comment: vou postar como eu fiz.

select itensVenda.idVenda, itensVenda.idProd, itensVenda.qtd, produtos.id, produtos.descricao, produtos.foto, venda.id, venda.valor from produtos INNER JOIN itensVenda ON produtos.id = itensVenda.idProd INNER JOIN venda ON itensVenda.idVenda = venda.id WHERE itensVenda.idVenda = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM venda WHERE id = id)

e na pagina que chama coloquei um script em javascript redirecionando assim:

echo 'location.href="ver_compra_final.php?id=$id"

Answer (score 0):

vou postar como eu fiz.

select itensVenda.idVenda, itensVenda.idProd, itensVenda.qtd, produtos.id, produtos.descricao, produtos.foto, venda.id, venda.valor from produtos INNER JOIN itensVenda ON produtos.id = itensVenda.idProd INNER JOIN venda ON itensVenda.idVenda = venda.id WHERE itensVenda.idVenda = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM venda WHERE id = id)

e na pagina que chama coloquei um script em javascript redirecionando assim:

echo 'location.href="ver_compra_final.php?id=$id";';